# Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 stuck on gnome startup (on battery only)

Tags: boot, 18.04, gnome, kernel, 20.04

I am facing a weird problem in gnome startup. Gnome startup gets stuck (before login screen) on battery BUT not when my laptop is connected to power.

I am running ubuntu 18.04 on Thinkpad T495 (AMD ryzen 3500u pro). Recently upgraded to the latest 5.3 kernel (via bionic stable ppt).

```
Linux ThinkPad-T495 5.3.0-26-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 16:40:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I was checking the journalctl logs but I am not entirely sure what sort of errors I need to focus on.

Any help on this is much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

This issue persists in ubuntu 20.04 as well.

And adding grub params `iommu=soft` solves this at least temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

Same bug on pretty much every distro I could try, s340 with 3500u here. Is this a known issue for the devs?

**Edit:** adding grub params `nomodeset` or `iommu=soft` solves this (idk at what cost) but it is a good temporary fix

Comment: Only `iommu=soft` fixed the issue decently. `nomodeset` was messing up with the display resolution. :-(
I found this post describing the implications of setting `iommu=soft`.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469153/what-are-the-implication-of-iommu-soft

Comment: And I can confirm that this issue persists in Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 still has the old kernel, I've heard some good things about the 5.6 kernel for amd iGPU's but it still isn't shipped with any of the mainstream distros. Guess it's something to keep an eye out for.

Comment: Well, I reinstalled 20.04 completely and then the boot issue went away! :O

Answer (score 0):

Installed Kernel 5.5 according to this guide: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/install-kernel-5-5-ubuntu/

Currently running 5.5.0-050500-generic which appears to resolve the issue. I am able to boot my laptop (T495/Ryzen) on battery now and did not see any other problems so far. USB works for me.

Only one error message remains in journalctl

```
[drm:dm_helpers_parse_edid_caps [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Couldn't read SADs: -2
```

Comment: Last boot brought me back to no login screen.  
Two more errors in journalctl reminding me of previous behavior with 5.4 kernel:  
journalctl -p err -b -1   
`Apr 28 21:19:21 ThinkPad-T495 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout, signaled seq=1, emitted seq=5  

Apr 28 21:19:21 ThinkPad-T495 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process Xorg pid 1170 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1178  

Apr 28 21:19:25 martin-ThinkPad-T495 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_cs_ioctl [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to initialize parser -125!`

Comment: I reinstalled 20.04 completely and then the boot issue went away! :O

Answer (score 0):

I disabled IOMMU in my bios and the laptop boots perfectly on battery now.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the new 5.8 kernel with:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge
```

be aware that this is official experimental kernel until they release the non-edge.

Xwayland edge still not out.

It will fix the problem, although I have another problem now with USB and BT suspending after a while.