# Ubuntu 22.04 usb not working (when running on battery)

Tags: drivers, 22.04, mouse, hp, battery

This is an extension of my earlier [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480412/usb-keyboard-and-mouse-dont-work-after-upgrade-to-22-04). There I thought `tlp` was the culprit and stopped the service and it worked. But when I try to run my laptop on battery, again USB devices are not working. Work for few seconds and then stops.

`lsusb` shows my devices and `dmesg`

```
[    1.903341] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0610, bcdDevice=60.60
[    1.903347] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    1.903350] usb 3-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    1.919601] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=250e, bcdDevice= 1.24
[    1.919608] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.919612] usb 1-3: Product: Dell Laser Mouse MS3220
[    1.919615] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Dell Computer Corp
[    1.946309] hub 3-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.946662] hub 3-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.959834] input: Dell Computer Corp Dell Laser Mouse MS3220 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:413C:250E.0002/input/input16


[   50.021872] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.3: WARNING: Host System Error
[   61.509372] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command
[   61.509412] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[   61.509439] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: HC died; cleaning up
[   61.509462] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   61.509467] usb 3-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   61.513144] usb 3-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[   61.518612] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
```

In `tlp-stat`

> Bus 001 Device 002 ID 413c:250e control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms = -1000 -- Dell Computer Corp. Dell Laser Mouse MS3220 (usbhid)

I had tried installing `linux-hwe-22.04`, stopping `tlp` , configuring tlp as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231692/ubuntu-20-04-usb-not-working-when-running-on-battery).

I am really frustrated with Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: When you're on battery, your laptop supplies less power to its USB ports. What other devices are you powering via USB? Try: Purchase a "Powered USB Hub" locally or from Amazon or ... I realize that plugging the USB Hub into the wall anchors the laptop. Check your Manufacturer's documentation. Explore your BIOS. Is there a POWER section, and can you configure USB Power? YMMV.

Comment: It looks to me that the mouse is underpowered, and repeatedly coming to life, telling the hardware "I'm a mouse", then dying.

Comment: @waltinator I had tried finding any such config in BIOS, but couldnt find. My laptop model is `hp probook 455 g6` with `AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 2700U w`. This issue was not there with Ubuntu 20.04. I upgraded from it to 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long debugging days, I found the solution. It also related to `tlp`.

In `/etc/tlp.conf` file.

```
 Runtime Power Management for PCI(e) bus devices: on=disable, auto=enable.
# Default: on (AC), auto (BAT)

RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=on
```

I had to set `RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=on`, it was originally set auto. 
Now external usb keyboard and mouse are working without an issue on battery.